# Patching In-App Purchase hack; stuck on fourth step

Tags: ios, encoding, in-app-purchase, decoding

As  many of us know, there's been a recent situation with Apple where hackers are able to get any In-App Purchase for free.  Apple recently released *[this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html)* describing how to patch it, but I'm a bit confused on step #4 and would appreciate any help.

The first steps are to download their patch .h and .m, include it in your project, and link it against the Security framework.  Okay, good, got it.  Then Apple says:

`4. Provide a base64 encoder, a base64 decoder, and the action to perform when validation succeeds.`

What exactly does the part about the encoders mean I should do?  (The action to perform when validation succeeds is clear to me.)  I see the functions named `base64_encode` and `base64_decode` in the class, certainly.  But what is it asking for?  Is this like a special PIN number that only I know, to prevent hacking?  I'm not sure what to do here. I get the overall concepts of encoding and decoding, of course, but not the programmatic specifics of how to generate one properly in this situation.

The code as Apple writes it, if this helps any:

```
- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
{ 
#warning Replace this method.
    return nil;
}

- (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input length:(NSInteger *)length
{
#warning Replace this method.
    return nil;
}

#warning Implement this function.
char* base64_encode(const void* buf, size_t size)
{ return NULL; }

#warning Implement this function.
void * base64_decode(const char* s, size_t * data_len)
{ return NULL; }
```

I'm also perplexed that there are 2 encode and 2 decode functions.  I get that there's a pair that returns `NSString*`s, but why does the second pair return a `char*` and a `void*`? What are these functions expected to return?  I really don't get it.

Comment: I would use one of your Apple Support calls, if you are a registered developer (you get two per year - use them or lose them). This is too important to make a mistake on or use advice that may be incorrect.

Comment: @RoboticCat Hmm, that's a good idea. It seems strange to me that Apple didn't add some explanation to the webpage they gave us. They explain the easy things (download the code, add it to your project) step-by-step, and then leave us hanging at the part which requires actual code.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Have you checked his website? It says he has found a workaround for VerificationController. Should we even bother spending time on implementing this quick-fix?

Comment: @PreetKamalMinhas I could not find where it said that on his website. Can you link me to it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like they want a general-purpose base64 encoder. Try some of the code here:

http://cocoadev.com/wiki/BaseSixtyFour

(disclaimer: I have not tested any of this)

Here's a second one that's rather easier to read:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

Comment: The code on that page is formatted very badly, so I have trouble reading it. (ie. lines that should be code aren't formatted like code, lines that aren't code are formatted like code, it's hard to see where examples begin and end...)  I really appreciate you trying to point me in the right direction, but I don't think I've found the answer.  I'm also confused that the examples on that link have 1 encode and 1 decode function, but Apple wants 2-one of each that returns a string, then an encode that returns char* and decode that returns void*. Why void*? What do they want returned? /so lost

Comment: Hmm, also, trying to look through the link further... It seems most of the examples use the same encoding table, though some use huge decoding tables and others don't seem to populate the decoding table at all. So I'm wondering: if the encoding table is always the same, what's the point of it? Wouldn't it be easy to hack? For that matter, if it's always the same why didn't Apple just write the code? I am very perplexed by this whole matter...

Comment: It is odd isn't it. Perhaps it's to do with export restrictions on cryptographic functions? Anyway, I've added a second link to the answer that's worth a look. Much better arranged.

Comment: @WendiKidd Apple is famous for excellent products and crappy docs. All their docs, without exceptions, are written in a vaguely way, incomplete, dubious or all these options together. Why should they provide a complete solution for that if they can create one more vague doc? BTW, I hate their docs. If there were no forums on the web like these one, we would be doomed. Our luck is that we have exceptional programmers that are able to understand the Klingon language Apple uses. Thanks for everyone helping here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at a solution presented: [here](http://www.1771.in/objective-c-iphone-finalizing-apples-vague-quotverificationcontroller-mquot.html), posted by unknown author.

which contains the following code, which I tested and works for me:

```
//  single base64 character conversion
static int POS(char c)
{
    if (c>='A' && c<='Z') return c - 'A';
    if (c>='a' && c<='z') return c - 'a' + 26;
    if (c>='0' && c<='9') return c - '0' + 52;
    if (c == '+') return 62;
    if (c == '/') return 63;
    if (c == '=') return -1;

    [NSException raise:@"invalid BASE64 encoding" format:@"Invalid BASE64 encoding"];
    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
{
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:base64_encode(input, (size_t)length)];
}

- (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input length:(NSInteger *)length
{
    size_t retLen;
    uint8_t *retStr = base64_decode([input UTF8String], &retLen);
    if (length)
        *length = (NSInteger)retLen;
    NSString *st = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:retStr
                                             length:retLen
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    free(retStr);    // If base64_decode returns dynamically allocated memory
    return st;
}

char* base64_encode(const void* buf, size_t size)
{
    static const char base64[] =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    char* str = (char*) malloc((size+3)*4/3 + 1);

    char* p = str;
    unsigned char* q = (unsigned char*) buf;
    size_t i = 0;

    while(i < size) {
        int c = q[i++];
        c *= 256;
        if (i < size) c += q[i];
        i++;

        c *= 256;
        if (i < size) c += q[i];
        i++;

        *p++ = base64[(c & 0x00fc0000) >> 18];
        *p++ = base64[(c & 0x0003f000) >> 12];

        if (i > size + 1)
            *p++ = '=';
        else
            *p++ = base64[(c & 0x00000fc0) >> 6];

        if (i > size)
            *p++ = '=';
        else
            *p++ = base64[c & 0x0000003f];
    }

    *p = 0;

    return str;
}

void* base64_decode(const char* s, size_t* data_len_ptr)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);

    if (len % 4)
        [NSException raise:@"Invalid input in base64_decode" format:@"%d is an invalid length for an input string for BASE64 decoding", len];

    unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*) malloc(len/4*3);

    int n[4];
    unsigned char* q = (unsigned char*) data;

    for(const char*p=s; *p; )
    {
        n[0] = POS(*p++);
        n[1] = POS(*p++);
        n[2] = POS(*p++);
        n[3] = POS(*p++);

        if (n[0]==-1 || n[1]==-1)
            [NSException raise:@"Invalid input in base64_decode" format:@"Invalid BASE64 encoding"];

        if (n[2]==-1 && n[3]!=-1)
            [NSException raise:@"Invalid input in base64_decode" format:@"Invalid BASE64 encoding"];

        q[0] = (n[0] << 2) + (n[1] >> 4);
        if (n[2] != -1) q[1] = ((n[1] & 15) << 4) + (n[2] >> 2);
        if (n[3] != -1) q[2] = ((n[2] & 3) << 6) + n[3];
        q += 3;
    }

    // make sure that data_len_ptr is not null
    if (!data_len_ptr)
        [NSException raise:@"Invalid input in base64_decode" format:@"Invalid destination for output string length"];

    *data_len_ptr = q-data - (n[2]==-1) - (n[3]==-1);

    return data;
}
```

Comment: That link is directly ripping the content from this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633577/iphone-finalizing-apples-vague-verificationcontroller-m?lq=1) which is actually a duplicate of this one...  I hadn't had a chance to look over the code yet, though.  I will do so and get back to you; thanks :)