# iPhone - finalizing Apple's vague "VerificationController.m"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to implement the new [VerificationController.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html) class that Apple released to fix the in-app purchase fraud problem.

As everything released by Apple, this is one more vague, incomplete and bad explained document with a lot of voids and unknowns that cannot be circumvented/understood by everyone.

I am trying to implement that, but at the end of the code we see these four methods:

```
- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
{
#warning Replace this method.
    return nil;
}

- (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input length:(NSInteger *)length
{
#warning Replace this method.
    return nil;
}

#warning Implement this function.
char* base64_encode(const void* buf, size_t size)
{ return NULL; }

#warning Implement this function.
void * base64_decode(const char* s, size_t * data_len)
{ return NULL; }
```

You can see that Apple was lazy to implement the C functions at the end of the code. As my C/C++ abilities stink, I see I need to implement these two functions in C/C++ and that they must return char and void (???). Other people have posted routines to do that on SO, but they are either in Objective-C or not returning chars and void (??).

**NOTE: this is another problem I have: how can a method return void if it is used by Apple in this form?**

```
uint8_t *purchase_info_bytes = base64_decode([purchase_info_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],                                                 &purchase_info_length);
```

shouldn't it be returning uint8_t?

**NOTE2: another problem I have is that apple says base64_encode is required but it is not being used on the code provided by them. I think they are smoking bad stuff or my C/C++ knowledge really stink.**

So, returning to my first question. Can someone post/point a method that can do the job that follows the requirements of the declared methods base64_encode and base64_decode? Please refrain from posting objective-c methods that are not compatible with these requirements imposed by Apple.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not `void`, it is `void *` which is the plain-C equivalent of `id`.  It needs to be this way because base64 represents an arbitrary object of unknown type.

Comment: ok, thanks. That solves the first problem.

Comment: The same question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612897/patching-in-app-purchase-hack-stuck-on-fourth-step/11613710#11613710

Comment: I know, but the answer given there do not follow the c style required by the correct answer.

Comment: thanks for every one helping and to those not helping and down voting a legitimate question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This ***solution*** should be pretty straight forward, which includes all the methods to populate the missing information.  Tested and functional within the sandbox.

```
//  single base64 character conversion
static int POS(char c)
{
    if (c>='A' && c<='Z') return c - 'A';
    if (c>='a' && c<='z') return c - 'a' + 26;
    if (c>='0' && c<='9') return c - '0' + 52;
    if (c == '+') return 62;
    if (c == '/') return 63;
    if (c == '=') return -1;

    [NSException raise:@"invalid BASE64 encoding" format:@"Invalid BASE64 encoding"];
    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)encodeBase64:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length
{
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:base64_encode(input, (size_t)length)];
}

- (NSString *)decodeBase64:(NSString *)input length:(NSInteger *)length
{
    size_t retLen;
    uint8_t *retStr = base64_decode([input UTF8String], &retLen);
    if (length)
        *length = (NSInteger)retLen;
    NSString *st = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:retStr
                                             length:retLen
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    free(retStr);    // If base64_decode returns dynamically allocated memory
    return st;
}

char* base64_encode(const void* buf, size_t size)
{
    static const char base64[] =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    char* str = (char*) malloc((size+3)*4/3 + 1);

    char* p = str;
    unsigned char* q = (unsigned char*) buf;
    size_t i = 0;

    while(i < size) {
        int c = q[i++];
        c *= 256;
        if (i < size) c += q[i];
        i++;

        c *= 256;
        if (i < size) c += q[i];
        i++;

        *p++ = base64[(c & 0x00fc0000) >> 18];
        *p++ = base64[(c & 0x0003f000) >> 12];

        if (i > size + 1)
            *p++ = '=';
        else
            *p++ = base64[(c & 0x00000fc0) >> 6];

        if (i > size)
            *p++ = '=';
        else
            *p++ = base64[c & 0x0000003f];
    }

    *p = 0;

    return str;
}

void* base64_decode(const char* s, size_t* data_len_ptr)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);

    if (len % 4)
        [NSException raise:@"Invalid input in base64_decode" format:@"%d is an invalid length for an input string for BASE64 decoding", len];

    unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*) malloc(len/4*3);

    int n[4];
    unsigned char* q = (unsigned char*) data;

    for(const char*p=s; *p; )
    {
        n[0] = POS(*p++);
        n[1] = POS(*p++);
        n[2] = POS(*p++);
        n[3] = POS(*p++);

        if (n[0]==-1 || n[1]==-1)
            [NSException raise:@"Invalid input in base64_decode" format:@"Invalid BASE64 encoding"];

        if (n[2]==-1 && n[3]!=-1)
            [NSException raise:@"Invalid input in base64_decode" format:@"Invalid BASE64 encoding"];

        q[0] = (n[0] << 2) + (n[1] >> 4);
        if (n[2] != -1) q[1] = ((n[1] & 15) << 4) + (n[2] >> 2);
        if (n[3] != -1) q[2] = ((n[2] & 3) << 6) + n[3];
        q += 3;
    }

    // make sure that data_len_ptr is not null
    if (!data_len_ptr)
        [NSException raise:@"Invalid input in base64_decode" format:@"Invalid destination for output string length"];

    *data_len_ptr = q-data - (n[2]==-1) - (n[3]==-1);

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Sorry disturbing you with this again, but I have installed Xcode 4.4 and Mountain Lion today and after analyzing the code with Xcode, it is complaining of logic error on this line "data_len_ptr = q-data - (n[2]==-1) - (n[3]==-1);" it points to n[2]==-1 saying *the left operand of == is a garbage value*. Do you possible know how I can silence that? Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, under the assumption that the data_len_ptr value is nil, then the following line would be a garbage (irrelevant) instruction.  I assume you were analyzing within Xcode.  I see the same warning.  My best guess would be to remove the line and test for the nil value before running the function so you can handle the error and silence the warning.

Comment: **remove**
    if (!data_len_ptr)
        [NSException raise:...

**Keep**
    *data_len_ptr = q-data - (n[2]==-1) - (n[3]==-1);

*Example*
    uint8_t *signature_bytes = base64_decode([signature_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], &signature_length);

**Change and test for the warning with something like**

    if (&signature_length)
        signature_bytes = base64_decode([signature_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], &signature_length);
    else 
        //handle the issue.. 

Aside from that, no i don't know how to silence that warning.

Comment: So when does data from the decode get freed? Seems like there is a memory leak in Apple's example...

Comment: The static analyzer warning is talking about "the left operand of ==" which is n. You can always silence this warning by first initializing the n array to zeros. So change "int n[4];" to "int n[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};". Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base 64 encode function for `NSString` to `NSString`:

```
+(NSString *) encodeString:(NSString *)inString
{
    NSData *data = [inString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //Point to start of the data and set buffer sizes
    int inLength = [data length];
    int outLength = ((((inLength * 4)/3)/4)*4) + (((inLength * 4)/3)%4 ? 4 : 0);
    const char *inputBuffer = [data bytes];
    char *outputBuffer = malloc(outLength);
    outputBuffer[outLength] = 0;

    //64 digit code
    static char Encode[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    //start the count
    int cycle = 0;
    int inpos = 0;
    int outpos = 0;
    char temp;

    outputBuffer[outLength-1] = '=';
    outputBuffer[outLength-2] = '=';

    while (inpos < inLength){
        switch (cycle) {
            case 0:
                outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[(inputBuffer[inpos]&0xFC)>>2];
                cycle = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                temp = (inputBuffer[inpos++]&0x03)<<4;
                outputBuffer[outpos] = Encode[temp];
                cycle = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[temp|(inputBuffer[inpos]&0xF0)>> 4];
                temp = (inputBuffer[inpos++]&0x0F)<<2;
                outputBuffer[outpos] = Encode[temp];
                cycle = 3;                  
                break;
            case 3:
                outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[temp|(inputBuffer[inpos]&0xC0)>>6];
                cycle = 4;
                break;
            case 4:
                outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[inputBuffer[inpos++]&0x3f];
                cycle = 0;
                break;                          
            default:
                cycle = 0;
                break;
        }
    }

    NSString *pictemp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:outputBuffer];
    free(outputBuffer); 

    return pictemp;
}
```

and Here is a base 64 decode function for `NSString` to `NSString`:

```
+(NSString *) decodeString:(NSString *)inString
{
    const char* string = [inString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSInteger inputLength = inString.length;

    static char decodingTable[128];

    static char encodingTable[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
        decodingTable[encodingTable[i]] = i;
    }

    if ((string == NULL) || (inputLength % 4 != 0)) {
        return nil;
    }

    while (inputLength > 0 && string[inputLength - 1] == '=') {
        inputLength--;
    }

    NSInteger outputLength = inputLength * 3 / 4;
    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:outputLength];
    uint8_t* output = data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger inputPoint = 0;
    NSInteger outputPoint = 0;
    while (inputPoint < inputLength) {
        char i0 = string[inputPoint++];
        char i1 = string[inputPoint++];
        char i2 = inputPoint < inputLength ? string[inputPoint++] : 'A'; /* 'A' will decode to \0 */
        char i3 = inputPoint < inputLength ? string[inputPoint++] : 'A';

        output[outputPoint++] = (decodingTable[i0] << 2) | (decodingTable[i1] >> 4);
        if (outputPoint < outputLength) {
            output[outputPoint++] = ((decodingTable[i1] & 0xf) << 4) | (decodingTable[i2] >> 2);
        }
        if (outputPoint < outputLength) {
            output[outputPoint++] = ((decodingTable[i2] & 0x3) << 6) | decodingTable[i3];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",data);

    NSString *finalString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    return finalString;
}
```

These were pieced together from examples I found in various places on the internet when I was searching for them a while ago.  They, may be easier for you to implement.  I just created a `Base64` class and placed these methods in it.

Comment: thanks, It would be easy to convert if I knew C/C++ but as I said,  my C/C++ abilities stink. This is why I have asked for the answer to be as required by Apple, that is, in C/C++ style. Apple values come in C form and requires C style results. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your decode function above is `NSString` to `NSString`.  The Encode function is `(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length` to `NSString`.  You can convert your `(const uint8_t *)input` to `NSString` using `NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:input];`  The above gives you everything you need to know other than that one line conversion.

Comment: Sorry disturbing you with this again, but I have installed Xcode 4.4 and Mountain Lion today and after analyzing the code with Xcode, it is complaining of logic error on this line "*data_len_ptr = q-data - (n[2]==-1) - (n[3]==-1);" it points to **n[2]==-1** saying *the left operand of == is a garbage value*. Do you possible know how I can silence that? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't even see that in the code.  That's from a different answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the C wrappers around Justin's answer:

```
char* base64_encode(const void* buf, size_t size)
{ 
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(void*)buf length:size];
    NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    return [[_Class_ encode:string] UTF8String];
}

void* base64_Decode (const char* s, size_t* data_len)
{
    NSString* result = [_Class_ decode:[NSString stringWithCString:s encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    *data_len = result.length;
    return [result UTF8String];
}
```

Where *Class* is the class that contains Justin's functions.

Comment: You don't need to know about it - you just need to cut and paste :)