# IPhone NSData to UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios

my NSData object contains within byte of a photo.
I would like to convert this object to a UIImage.
My problem is that he could not give a name all'oogetto UIImage. example myphoto.jpg

this is my code:

```
NSString * bytestring =(NSString *)[bean image];

//contain byte of my photo
NSData * byte = [bytestring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:byte];


UIButton *bt=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,80,100,100)];

[bt setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.boxView addSubview:bt];
```

the button does not display my photos.
how can I do?

Comment: What is the real value (without the cast) of `[bean image]`?

Comment: bean->_image:
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAAAAAAAD/4QBaRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAABG6ADAAQAAAABAAABgQAAAAAAAP/bAEMAAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAf/   ec....  maybe I'm not byte real? and the reason for this?   I'm sorry I edited your question: (

Comment: Looks like a base64 encoded image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appears that `[bean image]` is actually a base 64 encoding of the image's data, you need to use a method to convert the encoded data back into unencoded data.

There is no standard method for this but there are plenty you can find and use. Your code then becomes something like this:

```
NSString *byteString = [bean image]; // no need for a cast if it's already an NSString
NSData *byte = // call some method to convert base 64 encoded string into an NSData object
```

Have a look at:

[convert base64 decoded NSData to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832165/convert-base64-decoded-nsdata-to-nsstring)

Comment: <Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
thank you very much for your response. I get this error now: (for some reason the file and corrupt?